# Test management tool for manual and automation

Tags: automated-testing, test-management

I would like to know which test automation tool, other than Quality Center and QTP, is the most widely used and has the most robust features.

The automation tool and the scripting language are needed for a .NET application.

Also does anyone know about CLICTEST (test management tool)?

Comment: On SQA, we prefer questions that can be considered to have a "correct" answer.  What is the correct answer for, "Also does anyone know about CLICTEST (test management tool)?"  Do you literally want to know if anyone knows about CLICTEST, or is there something in particular you want to know about it?

Comment: I want to know if any one knows abt clictest or if any of the organisation is using this .... would lik to get the technical features

Answer (score 2):

- In my organization we are using Jira as test management tool and Selenium for UI automation.The framework used is TestNG. There is a plugin for Jira called Hiptest which can be used for creating and executing test cases. It has an additional option to work it with on automation too.
- Hiptest is good from my small experience. Simple to run test suites and it is integrated with Jira so issues can be linked to Jira when found during test execution.
- If someone has better options, it would be great.

Comment: does any one know about Kovair test management tool

Comment: just to complete the answer, Hiptest does support export to C#/Nunit and Specflow to test .NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

We also use JIRA and are just starting to use X-Ray for test management. X-Ray introduces three new issues types: Test, Test Set and Test Execution. A Test can be manual or automated and the Give-When-Then Gherkin syntax used by Cucumber is supported.

I cannot say if it is a better option than Hiptest but it is *an* option.